# Timing bug in our game, currentTimeMillis freeze?

Tags: android

When testing our game, that is heavily dependent on `System.currentTimeMillis()`, we are experiencing an annoying bug.

Our game uses an array of delta timestamps that indicates when certain things should happen. These timestamps matches a piece of music that is being played.

Testing at home gives us no problems at all. It's impossible to reproduce the bug while testing from our home.

But testing while driving around in the car, between cities, gives us sync problems between the timestamps and the music. My best guess is that Android freeze up the system, including the system timer because it's switching network, or looking for a signal?

I've tried inserting a fake hick-up in the game, by making the thread sleep a few seconds when I press a certain button. This freezes the screen (obviously), but everything is still syncing fine when the sleep is over.

The only way to reproduce this bug, is to take a trip by car or bus or train - which of course is most probably where most people will be when playing our game.

The question is of course,

- what to do about it?
- Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what is your game?can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: It's here now: www.PirateDiamonds.com :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html).

> **System.currentTimeMillis()** is the standard "wall" clock (time and
>   date) expressing milliseconds since the epoch. The wall clock can be
>   set by the user or the phone network (see setCurrentTimeMillis(long)),
>   so the time may jump backwards or forwards unpredictably.

---

> uptimeMillis() is counted in milliseconds since the system was booted.
>   This clock stops when the system enters deep sleep (CPU off, display
>   dark, device waiting for external input), but is not affected by clock
>   scaling, idle, or other power saving mechanisms. This is the basis for
>   most interval timing such as Thread.sleep(millls),
>   Object.wait(millis), and **System.nanoTime()**. This clock is guaranteed
>   to be **monotonic**, and is suitable for interval timing when the interval
>   does not span device sleep.

I think it's better to use [System.nanoTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29).

Comment: I ended up using `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and so far we haven't seen the error again. Thanks!